# Review queue in the topbar makes a man sad when he can't act upon it

Tags: feature-request, review

These two keep tempting me to click on them, even though deep down in my heart I know I have reached the limit on both. It pains me to see bad questions/answers while being helpless to do anything about it.

[image]

Why torture a man by shoving it in his face? And in such bright colors, on top of that!

Comment: Ah, I spent some time looking for related questions and saw nothing in the sidebar either.. Sorry for duplicating.